# Why is $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\cos(x-y) = -\sin(x-y)$ but $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\cos(x-y)$ = $\sin(x-y)$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Why is $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\cos(x-y) = -\sin(x-y)$ but $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\cos(x-y)$ = $\sin(x-y)$?

(According to wolfarmalpha)

---

Sorry for this question,

but  as far as I know, $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\cos(t) = -\sin(t).$

Why is $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\cos(x-y) = -\sin(x-y)$ but $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\cos(x-y)$?

NOTE: this is a partial derivative.

Thanks and again sorry for asking that.

Comment: there is no "sorry" with learning science :)

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh I'm feeling sorry to ask such stupid question .. can you answer my question please?

Comment: user 117757 answerd you

Comment: But $\frac\partial{\partial y}\cos(x-y)$ what?

Comment: @Mike $- \sin(t)$. for some reason it didn't posted in the title ..

Comment: "=" you mean?  It's missing in 2 other places in addition to the title.  "But $\frac\partial{\partial y}\cos(x-y)$" makes as much sense as "but 3".  It's not a complete thought and makes it unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Mike yes, user117757 explained me this good .. thanks anyway

Comment: @use4r1798362 : I don't mean to pick on you, but for the benefit of other users, please fix your title and your question, because they don't make sense (even if someone guessed what you meant).

Comment: @StefanSmith - My fault - fixed.

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh : Mathematics is not a science "Many philosophers believe that mathematics is not experimentally falsifiable, and thus not a science according" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics, but you are right, there is no "sorry" in learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apply the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\cos(x-y))=\frac{\partial}{\partial (x-y)}(\cos(x-y))\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-y)=-\sin(x-y)*1$$

Similarly for the partial derivative in terms of $y$.

Comment: I have something to tell you. You're a ninja. I was literally about to post that same exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

One more way: expand $\cos (x-y)=\sin x \sin y + \cos x \cos y$ and take the derivative

Answer (score 0):

$$v(x,y)=u(x-y)\implies\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=u'(x-y)=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$